# How to delete Closed testing track build in Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I accidentally created a Closed testing track instead of Internal Testing track on Google Play Console (New UI). Now, I want to remove or make sure it doesn't roll out to the public since I need to push my Live build over it in the Production track. Currently, I have paused the Closed testing track build and Google shows the below option, so will it be ok, if I click on the Review and Publish button?
I referred to other posts on Stackoverflow, but they suggested deleting the track directly but it was referring the Classic UI if Google Play Console.

Can anyone suggest a better idea?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Answering my question, since this can help someone. If you have accidentally created a release that was not supposed to, just make sure to create another build with higher version code and it will solve your issue. (Received reply from Google support)

**Google support response:**

*Please note that you have to submit first a higher APK version for reviewing and leave the APK version on the Closed Testing track under 'Changes ready to publish' while waiting for the reviewing procedure. Once they are both under 'Changes ready to publish', you can click the Review and Publish button so you can supersede it successfully*

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the full story. We have got many old closed testing tracks sitting around, and we have released and published many higher APK versions since then, but they still remain.